# Change the IFRAME address when you press the "Enter" key on the keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an HTML page with two IFRAME windows.

I want to change the addresses between them when the "Enter" key is pressed.
Thanks!

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">
<iframe class="g" src="www.example.com"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"  height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="overlay"><iframe src="www.wow.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px"  height="205px" width="360px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<style>  #overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 430px;
      right: 15px;

  color: #FFF; 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}

.g {
    height: 100%;
}

#v {
  z-index: 1;
}</style></div><div style='text-align: right;position: fixed;z-index:9999999;bottom: 0; width: 100%;cursor: pointer;line-height: 0;display:block !important;'></div></body>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Apply Javascript here.

Onsubmit/onclick enter key you have to set the src attribute of iframe tag.